# How to load a ViewController(Xib) from interface builder into a ViewController in code. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have an array of `BreakdownViewController` which is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

```
var allViewControllers = [BreakdownViewController]()
```

I use a for loop to populate the array with a number of BreakdownViewControllers

```
for(var i: Int = 0; i < 5; i++){
    // Add new instance of BreakdownViewController to array
    allViewController.append(BreakdownViewController())
}
```

However I want to attach the xib in interface builder that is linked to BreakdownViewController and attached it to each instance in the array so they all look the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var allViewControllers = [BreakdownViewController]()
for(var i: Int = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var xibName = NSStringFromClass(BreakdownViewController.self) as String
    var viewController = BreakdownViewController(nibName: xibName, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle());
    allViewController.append(viewController)
}
```

Comment: I get the following error `reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle`. I feel I haven't set something?

Comment: I'm not sure how your project is set up. If you're using storyboards then you're better off using: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BreakdownViewController") as UIViewController . Also make sure your .xib / .storyboard file belongs to your project main target. Edited my answer to pass NSBundle.mainBundle() instead of nil.